# why I have Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I'm making a gem-puzzle. When I just use html and js I generate elements dynamically and put onclick on each one and when I click on it, everything works well, but when I connected the webpack it doesn't work. I rewrite the function showTable with createElement instead concatenation. And now I have an error Maximum call stack size exceeded at moveThisTile. I don't understand why? How can I fixed that? Please, help me to make this code work. There is my full code https://codepen.io/tomas777/pen/abZjZav?editors=1111

```
function startNewGame() {
  let arrayOfNumbers = new Array();
  let arrayHasNumberBeenUsed;
  let randomNumber = 0;
  let count = 0;
  moves = 0;
  rows = document.getElementById("rows").value;
  columns = document.getElementById("columns").value;
  textMoves.innerHTML = moves;
  arrayForBoard = new Array(rows);
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    arrayForBoard[i] = new Array(columns);
  }
  arrayHasNumberBeenUsed = new Array( rows * columns );
  for (let i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++){
    arrayHasNumberBeenUsed[i] = 0;
  }
 for (let i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++){
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*rows * columns);
    if (arrayHasNumberBeenUsed[randomNumber] == 0) {
      arrayHasNumberBeenUsed[randomNumber] = 1;
      arrayOfNumbers.push(randomNumber);
    }else 
    {
      i--;
    }
  }
  count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      arrayForBoard[i][j] = arrayOfNumbers[count];
      
      count++;
    }
  }
  showTable();
}
function showTable() {
    let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    document.querySelector('#table').appendChild(tbody);
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      let cell = document.createElement('td');
      if (arrayForBoard[i][j] == 0) {
        cell.className = 'blank';
      } else {
        cell.className = 'tile';
        cell.onclick = moveThisTile(i, j); 
        cell.innerHTML =arrayForBoard[i][j];
      }
      tr.appendChild(cell);
    } 
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  } 
};

function moveThisTile(tableRow, tableColumn) {
  if (checkIfMoveable(tableRow, tableColumn, "up") ||
      checkIfMoveable(tableRow, tableColumn, "down") ||
      checkIfMoveable(tableRow, tableColumn, "left") ||
      checkIfMoveable(tableRow, tableColumn, "right") ) {
    incrementMoves();
  } else {
    alert("ERROR: Cannot move tile!\nTile must be next to a blank space.");
  }
  if (checkIfWinner()) {
    alert("Congratulations! You solved the puzzle in " + moves + " moves.");
    startNewGame();
  }
}

function checkIfMoveable(rowCoordinate, columnCoordinate, direction) {
  let rowOffset = 0;
  let columnOffset = 0;
  if (direction == "up"){rowOffset = -1;}
  else if (direction == "down"){rowOffset = 1;}
  else if (direction == "left"){columnOffset = -1;}
  else if (direction == "right"){columnOffset = 1;}  
  if (rowCoordinate + rowOffset >= 0 && columnCoordinate + columnOffset >= 0 &&
    rowCoordinate + rowOffset < rows && columnCoordinate + columnOffset < columns
  ){
    if ( arrayForBoard[rowCoordinate + rowOffset][columnCoordinate + columnOffset] == 0){
      arrayForBoard[rowCoordinate + rowOffset][columnCoordinate + columnOffset] = arrayForBoard[rowCoordinate][columnCoordinate];
      arrayForBoard[rowCoordinate][columnCoordinate] = 0;
      showTable();
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false; 
}
function checkIfWinner(){
  let count = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      if (arrayForBoard[i][j] != count){
    if ( !(count === rows * columns && arrayForBoard[i][j] === 0 )){
      return false;
    }
      }
      count++;
    }
  }  
  return true;
}
```

Comment: What is `checkIfWinner` and `startNewGame`?

Comment: `showTable` calls `moveThisTile` calls `checkIfMovable` calls `showTable` calls `moveThisTile` ... you get it now? perhaps you meant `cell.onclick = () => moveThisTile(i, j); ` rather than calling `moveThisTile` immediately

Comment: @RichieBendall checkIfWinner checks if the game is over and if click on the button start new game, the function startNewGame will work

Comment: @Tom Can you include those functions in the question?

Comment: @RichieBendall done

Comment: @Tom Your code enters an infinite loop: `moveThisTile()` calls `checkIfMoveable()` which calls `showTable()` which called `moveThisTile()`.

Comment: @RichieBendall and how I can rewrite?

Comment: @Tom By commenting out line 152, the code no longer enters into an infinite loop